# Keybord shortcut to add new driver

Tags: animation, shortcut, drivers

Usually you press <kbd>D</kbd> and can add a driver. But it doesn't work anymore. What causes this? The Keyboard shortcut exists but doesn't work. If i hover the Cursor over the desired section and press <kbd>D</kbd> it should turn purple. Instead i need to right-click on it, click on add drivers, and manually create later.

Comment: I have the same issue and don't know why... but try ctrl+D instead

Comment: @lemon That would be a bit quicker but not as quick as it used to be.